A question about Guru shishya relation?
Can a Hindu guru who worships muslim gurus be considered as a guru in hinduism..I mean is deeksha taken from them valid?

Can you please clarify what you mean by "Muslim Gurus"? You mean Islamic teachers? Any specific person you have in mind?

By muslim gurus I mean dargahs and fakirs.

I) Your first question Can a Hindu guru who worships muslim gurus be considered as a guru in hinduism.
According to Sri Shankara Digvijayam [Ch-5], Ādi Śaṅkarācārya(आदि शङ्कराचार्य), was on his way to the Kashi Visvanatha temple, after finishing his bath in Ganga, when he came across a Caṇḍāla(चण्डाल) and his four dogs. He asked the Caṇḍālato move away from him, as was the custom in those days, to which the Caṇḍāla questioned him in two Sanskrit verses:
अन्नमायादन्नमयमथवा चैतन्यमेव चैतन्यात्य। तिवर दूरीकर्तुं वाञ्छसि किं ब्रूहि गच्छगच्छेति॥

To move matter from matter, or to separate spirit from Spirit?
O best among the twice born, which of these two do you wish to achieve by 
saying, “Move away, move away”?

Astonished Śaṅkarācārya replied to the questions in five verses, known as Manīshā Panchakam (मनीषा पंचकम्), and touched the feet of Chandala, as a way to show respect towards him. Those verses are as given below:
जाग्रत्स्वप्नसुषुप्तिषु स्फुटतरा या संविदुज्जृम्भते या ब्रह्मादिपिपीलिकान्ततनुषु प्रोता जगत्साक्षिणी
सैवाहं न च दृश्यवस्त्विति दृढप्रज्ञापि यस्यास्ति च्चण्डालोऽस्तु स तु द्विजोऽस्तु गुरुरित्येषा मनीषा मम ॥ १ ॥
In the waking, dream and deep sleep states, That which is their 
Illuminator, by which one comes to know and understand things
From the Creator down to the ant, that which is the very spark of life in 
them; the witness of the entire universe
That alone am I, and not the objects that are “seen”, firmly established 
in this Consciousness – if there is such a person, be he a Chandala or be he a Brahmana, 
such a one indeed is worthy of being a Guru. This is my firm conviction ॥ 1 ॥

ब्रह्मैवाहमिदं जगच्च सकलं चिन्मात्रविस्तारितं सर्वं चैतदविद्यया त्रिगुणयाऽशेषं मया कल्पितम् ।
इत्थं यस्य दृढा मतिस्सुखतरे नित्ये परे निर्मले चण्डालोऽस्तु स तु द्विजोऽस्तु गुरुरित्येषा मनीषा मम ॥ २ ॥
I am pure Consciousness, and this entire universe, is only an expansion of pure Consciousness
Out of this Maya all this that we see, made of the three gunas, has been conjured by imagination,
He whose intellect is firmly established in the all blissful, eternal, Supreme Reality,
be he a Chandala or be he a Brahmana, such a one is indeed worthy of being a Guru. 
This is my firm conviction.॥ 2 ॥

शश्वन्नश्वरमेव विश्वमखिलं निश्चित्य वाचा गुरो-र्नित्यं ब्रह्म निरन्तरं विमृशता निर्व्याजशान्तात्मना
भूतं भावि च दुष्कृतं प्रदहता संविन्मये पावके प्रारब्धाय समर्पितं स्ववपुरित्येषा मनीषा मम ॥ ३ ॥
Permanently in a state of flux is this entire world of change, reflect thus on the words of his Guru
"Brahman is Eternal" dwelling on this only, casting aside all dissimilar thoughts, his mind is quietened and poised
And all past and future residual Vasanas of evil deeds are burnt in the 
fire of Pure consciousness, He thereafter offers his body to Prarabdha
Such a one is worthy to be a Guru, be he a Chandala or a Brahmana,
this is my firm conviction. ॥ 3 ॥

या तिर्यङ्नरदेवताभिरहमित्यन्तः स्फुटा गृह्यते यद्भासा हृदयाक्षदेहविषया भान्ति स्वतोऽचेतनाः
तां भास्यैः पिहितार्कमण्डलनिभां स्फूर्तिं सदा भावय-गी निर्वृतमानसो हि गुरुरित्येषा मनीषा मम ॥ ४ ॥
Upon That which in animals, man and the Deities is, as the inner “I” or Ego clearly perceived to be present
Upon That Light by which the mind, senses and body instruments are enlivened, though in themselves inert
Upon that Radiance covered by dark clouds, yet shining forth from behind 
them he who always meditates a Yogi, with mind freed of all thoughts,
is indeed worthy of being a Guru, this is my firm conviction. ॥ 4 ॥

यत्सौख्याम्बुधिलेशलेशत इमे शक्रादयो निर्वृता यच्चित्ते नितरां प्रशान्तकलने लब्ध्वा मुनिर्निर्वृतः ।
यस्मिन्नित्यसुखाम्बुधौ गलितधीर्ब्रह्मैव न ब्रह्मविद् यः कश्चित्स सुरेन्द्रवन्दितपदो नूनं मनीषा मम ॥ ५॥ 
I am convinced that whoever has his mind dwelling upon the Great Being 
who is being worshipped by Indra and other gods and is thus completely at peace 
with himself has not only understood Brahman but he is himself that great Brahman, 
this is my firm conviction. ॥ 5 ॥

From the Manīshā Panchakam, Ādi Śaṅkarācārya accepted a Caṇḍāla as Guru; this  is extensible to Mleccha (म्लेच्छ/Mulsim) who can also be a Guru provided that he qualifies so! This is answered in the following question.
II) Your second and final question I mean is deeksha taken from them valid?
Kulārnava Tantra (कुलार्णव तंत्र) says about the qualification of Guru who is eligible to perform Mantra Dīksha (मन्त्र दीक्षा) to a shisya as give below:
भूतभव्यौ तन्त्रमन्त्रौ वेति यः शाक्तशाम्भवम् ।
वेधञ्च षड्विधां देवि स हि वेधकरो गुरुः ॥ ७२॥

Who knows the past, future, Tantra and Mantra, 
who knows the Doctrines of Sākta and Sāmbhu and also 
the six Vedhas he is the Guru who pierces the subtle.

Note: Vedha is of three types: Ānava, Sākta and Sāmbhava.
Each of these is further sub-divided into two, viz. Bāhya(outer) and Ābhyantara(inner).

-Kulārnava Tantra: 13.72

Kulārnava Tantra talks about six kinds of Guru as give below:
शैवे गुरुत्रयं प्रोक्तं वैष्णवे गुरुपञ्चकम् ।
वेदशास्त्रे शतशो गुरुरेकः कुलान्वये ॥ १२७ ॥

Three are the Gurus among Saivas; five among the Vaisnavas; hundreds in 
the Vedas and Sastras; but in the Kula there is only one Guru.॥ 127 ॥

प्रेरकः सूचकश्चैव वाचको दर्शकस्तथा ।
शिक्षको बोधकश्चैव षडेते गुरवः स्मृता ॥ १२८ ॥

Gurus are said to be of six kinds : 1. Preraka [impeller]; 2. Sūcaka [indicator]; 
3. Vācaka [explainer]; 4. Darsaka [shower]; 5. Siksaka [teacher]; 
6. Bodhaka [illuminator]. ॥ 128 ॥

पञ्चैते कार्यभूताः स्युं कारणं बोधको भवेत् ।
पूर्णाभिषेककर्ता यो गुरुस्तस्यैव पादुका ।
पूजनीया महेशानि बहुत्वेऽपि न संशयः ॥ १२९ ॥

Bodhaka, as the Cause. Inspite of many Gurus, the Guru who gives the full Initiation,
only his Paduka, O Mahesani! is to be venerated. There is no doubt about it.॥ 129 ॥

As discussed above, according to Kulārnava Tantra [13:127-129], there are six kinds of Guru which are:

Preraka (प्रेरकः/impeller): He is the one who impels interest that
leads to initiation.
Sūcaka (सूचक/indicator): This Guru indicates the sādhana in which
interest has been awakened.
Vācaka (वाचक/explainer): The one who explains the process and its
object.
Darsaka (दर्शक/shower): Guru who shows definitely the workings and
its aim in greater details.
Siksaka (शिक्षक/teacher): The teacher who actually teaches how to do
sadhana.
Bodhaka (बोधक/illuminator): Finally the Guru who lights up in the
disciple the lamp of knowledge mental and spiritual.

Of these the first five are, as it were, the effects of the last as the cause. For it is only the understanding knowledge imparted by Bodaka that brings to fruition all that is contributed by rest.
Instigation, inauguration, explanation, direction and teaching would remain barren unless they are taken up and assimilated in the knowledge that is lit.
Beware: How does one attain the state of a Bhodaka? Kulārnava Tantra answers this question in chapter-13, sloka-72 about eligibility for a person to become not only as Guru but also as a Bhodaka, as indicated above.
Conclusion:
Any body can be a Guru, whether he is a  Caṇḍāla or Mleccha(Mulsim), as supported by Ādi Śaṅkarācārya. Kulārnava Tantra, as discussed before, describes six kinds of Gurus and as long as one being a Bhodaka, he is eligible for a Guru.
